# How do I create and access a database for civiCRM

Tags: wordpress, database, installation

I am trying to install CiviCRM in WordPress to see if the small NGO I work with might be able to use it. I got a domain name and installed WordPress through BlueHost.com and turned on the CiviCRM plugin. It says the following problems exist, and they all appear to have to do with a database. I don't have any experience with software/programming/IT. 
It appears I need to give access to CiviCRM to do stuff, but I have no idea how to do that.

I would really appreciate your help!! Thank-you very much!!

Sharone

CiviCRM Database Details

- Does the server exist?
  OK (localhost)
- Are the access credentials correct?
  That username/password doesn't work:
- Can I access/create the database? 
  I can't create new databases and the database 'civicrm' doesn't exist. (user 'civicrm' doesn't have CREATE DATABASE permissions.)
- Can I access/create InnoDB tables in the database?
  Unable to create InnoDB tables. MySQL InnoDB support is required for CiviCRM but is either not available or not enabled in this MySQL database server. Could not determine if MySQL has InnoDB support. Assuming no.
- Can I create temporary tables in the database?
  Could not login to the database.
- Can I create lock tables in the database? 
  Could not connect to the database server.
- Can I create triggers in the database?
  Could not login to the database.

Comment: I have quite a bit of competences with software/programming/IT and I face the same problem (as far as I understand). I installed civiCRM on my OVH.com hosted Wordpress site.
The db user has write right but not the right to create DB. I have the same errors (see bellow). I don't understand why. On this kind of hosting you can for instance, have several Wordpress running with prefixed database tables. Can we do the same with civiCRM ? Does MySQL thread_stack meet minimum (192k) Could not connect to the database server.
Can I access/create the database? I can't create new databases and the databa

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  You have posted this as an answer but it doesn't really answer the question.  You are more likely to get a response if you post this as a new question.  If relevant, you can link back to this question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5843)

Answer (score 2):

For testing purpose, it could have been nice to install it locally using a virtual box for example following this documentation: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5.

But since you have stated that you have no experience in software/programming/IT, your best bet will be CiviCRM hosting providers: https://civicrm.org/providers/hosting

Comment: If you managed to install Wordpress and its database (and it sounds like you have) you could use the same database username/pwd to create the CiviCRM database (you need to run the CiviCRM install wizard which will let you enter the name of your Civi database, a username and pwd).  You might also want to just login to the CiviCRM Wordpress DEMO which is already set up and running, to try out various functions (http://wp45.demo.civicrm.org/)